# Pouchdb syncing error with couchdb is undefined

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, ts-loader

I am using PouchDB to sync to a local CouchDb on my Server, and I try to sync a couchdb from my laptop.

The code in my .ts file is as follows:

```
var localDB = new PouchDB('mylocaldb')

var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/easy_water')

localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
    live: false,
    retry: false
  }).on('change', function (change) {
    console.log(change);
  }).on('paused', function (info) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


console.log("fertig");
```

and the result in the browser is:

```
fertig
undefined
undefined
```

the remoteDatabase exists, so the remoteDatabase is not wrong

Answer (score 1):

Does your CouchDB listen to localhost? CORS enabled in CouchDB? 
Do you need credentials?
Try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.
Take a look at the browsers development tools (console).
Try to separate sync() into replicate.to() and replicate.from()

Comment: CORS is enabled, CouchDB settings are fine. I don't need credentials.

Separate sync() into replicate.to() and replicate.from() doesn't change anything

Comment: @brandart What's your browser and browser version? Today I face a problem with Chrome 65 and CORS.

Comment: I also use chrome but I also tried it with electron, doesn‘t work either

Comment: Did you check the firewall? Any errors thrown by PouchDB in Chrome DevTools?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?